# Docker django project problem with mysqlclient for using mysql

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django, docker, docker-compose

I have problem with docker container build process with docker compose, the django project that i want to build, has problem in `mysqlclient` library installation and usage,

I use pip cache for faster build process and lower internet download traffic, but in this way the mysqlclient library seems that did not completely installed :

```
#23 6.165 Collecting mysqlclient==2.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 24))
#23 6.166   Using cached mysqlclient-2.2.1-cp311-cp311-linux_x86_64.whl
```

If i run a db related command this error shown :

```
 > [web 21/23] RUN python3 manage.py collectstatic:
0.894   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
0.894     return import_module("%s.base" % backend_name)
0.894            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
0.894   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
0.895     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
0.895            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
0.895   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 17, in <module>
0.895     raise ImproperlyConfigured(
0.895 django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
0.895 Did you install mysqlclient?
```

Or inside container :
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
If i uninstall it and install it again without using cache, the problem goes away :

```
root@8c1a9b9b4e02:/opt/app# python3
Python 3.11.7 (main, Jan 11 2024, 10:43:21) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: libmysqlclient.so.21: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

After uninstall and install it again everything is works fine :
[image]

I use `python:3.11-slim` image and install all dependencies before going for this :

```
RUN apt install apt-utils python3-dev \
default-libmysqlclient-dev pkg-config gcc -y --no-install-recommends
```

The process of building this specific library is different when i not use cache and after that everything is works fine . why !?

- mysqlclient==2.2.1
- host : ubuntu 23.10
- django 4-5

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)